# Python3 - hangmanClearScreen

Tags: python-3.x, windows

After I finish my hangman game, when I clear the console, it clears everything. However, I want it to not clear the menu. How do I fix this?

Here is my code:

```
import random, os
import time

print("^^^^^^^^^^THIS IS HANGMAN^^^^^^^^^^")
print("1. Play Game ")
print("2. Quit Game ")
choice = input("Please enter option 1 or 2")

if choice == "1":

words = ["handkerchief", "accommodate", "indict", "impetuous"]
word = random.choice(words)
guess = ['_'] * len(word)
guesses = 7

while '_' in guess and guesses > 0:
    print(' '.join(guess))
    character = input('Enter character: ')

    if len(character) > 1:
        print('Only enter one character.')
        continue

    if character not in word:
        guesses -= 1

    for i, c in enumerate(word):
        if c == character:
            guess[i] = character

    if guesses == 0:
        print('You LOST!')
        break

    else:
        print('You have only', guesses, 'chances left to win.')

else:
    print(''.join(guess))
    print('You WON, well done')

time.sleep(2)
import os
os.system('clear')
```

I don't know how to make the code so that it only clears down to the menu

Comment: This is tagged as a Windows question, so, FYI, if you happen to have a "clear.exe" in `PATH`, it's not from a standard Windows installation. The CMD shell has an internal `cls` command to clear the console screen, e.g. `os.system('cls')`.

Answer (score 1):

simply wrap your menu in a function

```
def menu():
    print("^^^^^^^^^^THIS IS HANGMAN^^^^^^^^^^")
    print("1. Play Game ")
    print("2. Quit Game ")
```

and reprint it after you clear the console

```
import os
os.system('clear')
menu()
```

if you want your menu to still work after the clear, just include all the code you use to make your menu work into the menu() function. Good luck on your project

Comment: i know it says youre not meant to say thanks, but thanks because this was pretty last minute